# do I have the same result like transaction if I use Firestore increment in a batch operation?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am not sure how to use Firestore Increment in an atomic way. and I am little bit confused.

I have `capacity` as field in my document. simultaneous users can increase or decrease the value of `capacity` by updating the document. beside updating, in the same time, the user also needs to create some documents. previously I use transaction to ensure create and update operation will

so previously I use firestore transaction to ensure those operation either all of the operations succeed, or all of them failed.

but now I want to use Firebase Increment and batch operation like this

```
        val batch = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().batch()

        // 1. set event data in liked events subcollection
        val ref1 = FirestoreDocumentReference.user.getReference(user.uid).collection("likedEvents").document(likedEvent.eventID)
        val savedData1 : HashMap<String,Any> = hashMapOf(
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_EVENT_ID to likedEvent.eventID,
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_TITLE to likedEvent.title,
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_VENUE to likedEvent.venue,
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME to likedEvent.dateTimeStart,
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_THUMBNAIL_DOWNLOAD_PATH to likedEvent.thumbnailDownloadPath,
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_CREATED_AT to Calendar.getInstance().time
        )
        batch.set(ref1,savedData1)



        // 2. update the rankPoint and capacity of event
        val updateData : MutableMap<String,Any> = mutableMapOf(
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_RANKPOINT to FieldValue.increment(5),
            FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_CAPACITY to FieldValue.increment(-1)
        )
        val ref2 = FirestoreDocumentReference.event.getReference(likedEvent.eventID)
        batch.update(ref2,updateData)


        batch.commit().addOnSuccessListener {
            completion(true,null)
        }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            completion(false,e.localizedMessage)
        }
```

if I do something like this, do I have the same result like updating `capacity` using transaction ?

I have to ensure two things:

- capacity value update will not overlapping, if some users update the
  capacity value at the same time
- both create and update operations have to all succeed, or all of them failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch write operations are executed transactionally on the server.

The difference between a batch write and a transaction, is that in a transaction you get the document data on the client first, before sending that data and the updated values to the server. In a batch write you simply send all the updates to the server, without first getting any value. Since `FieldValue.increment()` allows changing a numeric field without the client first reading its value, this can be safely done in a batch operation.

So: yes, the updates will either all happen, or none of them will happen. And there is no chance of race conditions on the increments.